# JQuery and Javascript: Writing Better code - How can I improve on both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While still learning JavaScript and JQuery I am trying to implement the "DRY" principle as much as possible to write smarter, better and efficient code. 
The code below is the before:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#social-holder').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.circle-bg-fb').addClass('circle-bg-fb-end');
    $('.circle-bg-tw').addClass('circle-bg-tw-end');
    $('.circle-bg-g').addClass('circle-bg-g-end');
    $('.circle-bg-p').addClass('circle-bg-p-end');
}).click(function(){
    $('.circle-bg-fb').removeClass('circle-bg-fb-end');
    $('.circle-bg-tw').removeClass('circle-bg-tw-end');
    $('.circle-bg-g').removeClass('circle-bg-g-end');
    $('.circle-bg-p').removeClass('circle-bg-p-end');
});
```

});

And this is the After (to replace the code above):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elems = [$('i.circle-bg-fb'), $('i.circle-bg-tw'), $('i.circle-bg-p'), $('i.circle-bg-g')];
  var cls = ["circle-bg-fb-end", "circle-bg-tw-end", "circle-bg-p-end", "circle-bg-g-end",];

    $('div#social-holder').on("mouseenter", function(){
        for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].addClass(cls[i]);
        };
    }).on("click", function(){
        for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].removeClass(cls[i]);
        };
    });
});
```

Is there a better of writing the code above and on the second one mainly is it more efficient than the first one? Any better ways of doing this. Here is a [link](http://codepen.io/ChiefDesignz/pen/JdqWJz) to the pen I was practising on.

Comment: Might be better to post this over on Code Review (since it's already working and what not)

Comment: Just keep in mind that "better" is subjective and  less code is not always more efficient. If you are firing up a for loop just for 4 elements you are might be adding unnecessary complexity. Also, if keeping things lean and mean is your goal, jQuery is not a great solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

You've taken the dry principle a little too far. Your code is too hard to read and didn't really save you any lines of code.

That being said, you don't even need javascript to do what you're trying to do (now that's dry!). You could use the CSS :hover selector to perform the same effect, I think.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with the hover selector but once the first transition(out) is complete there is need to rely on a transition delay so that the icons pause before  the second(in) transition kicks in. Reason I used JQuery is to add a click function to trigger the second transition - plus for practise purposes too. I have updated the code using CSS hover and also included the JQuery as well. @dzylich

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have followed the general principle of turning multiple lines of nearly identical code into a loop over a data structure. But why not move the data structure out of the function? The way it is coded now, I would guess that JavaScript is going to recreate the data each time the function is called. Since the data is constant and does not depend on the function's arguments, define it outside the function.
And, by the way, I think this is a good application of DRY: I never want to see repeated blocks of code like that in my work!